# Add class to div that contain Dog 1 and rows in between

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code is automatically generated so I cannot add classes/id's etc by adding HTML so I am trying to do this using js. I truncated the content, but basically I want to add class "dog1" to the rows that pertain to Dog 1 and class "dog2" to the rows that pertain to Dog 2.

I tried using the script in the attached snippet:

```js
let dogCounter = 1;
let classAttribute = '';
const $trs = $('span:contains("Dog 1")').first().closest('div');

$trs.each((i, div) => {
  const selector = 'span:contains("Dog '+dogCounter+'")';
  if ($(div).find(selector).length) {
   classAttribute = 'dog'+dogCounter;
    dogCounter++;
  }
  $(div).addClass(classAttribute);
})
```

```css
.dog1 {
  color: red;
}
.dog2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>Dog 1 Name</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 1 Age</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 1 Weight</span></div>
<div>
<span>Date of last appointment</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 1 Number</span></div>
<div><span>Acceptance</span></div>
<div><div><span>Dog 1 Allergies</span></div></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Details</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Name</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Name</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Age</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Weight</span></div>
<div><span>Date of last appointment</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Number</span></div>
<div><span>Acceptance</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Allergies</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps :)
I only added the class to the span, so you may consider adding it to the parent div;
Also, there are divs that don't contain a "Dog *" pattern, so you may have to consider another approach;

Later edit: The rows in between can't be matched by a regex, so you may have to consider splitting your data by starting and ending columns ("Name" column may be the starting column, "Allergies" may be the ending column)

```js
const $dogSpans = $('span:contains("Dog")');

$dogSpans.each((i, span) => {
   matches = $(span).html().toString().match( /Dog [0-9]*/); //may find more than one match
   match = matches[0].toLowerCase(); //we only consider the first match (and we lowercase it)
   matchedClass = match.replace(/\s/g, ''); //we remove spaces to obtain a class name
   $(span).addClass(matchedClass);
})
```

```css
.dog1 {
  color: red;
}
.dog2 {
  color: blue;
}

.dog15 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span>Dog 1 Name</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 1 Age</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 1 Weight</span></div>
<div>
<span>Date of last appointment</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 1 Number</span></div>
<div><span>Acceptance</span></div>
<div><div><span>Dog 1 Allergies</span></div></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Details</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Name</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Name</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Age</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Weight</span></div>
<div><span>Date of last appointment</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Number</span></div>
<div><span>Acceptance</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Allergies</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 15 Name</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`:contains()` has terrible syntax it's a mess. A less error prone way is to use `.text()` to extract the text contents of each div then see if a particular substring exists using `.includes()`. Also, if you run `.each()` start one level higher than the target elements and use `.find()` if you want all descendants or `.children()` if you want the direct descendants.:

```
$(ancestor element(s)).find(target elements).each(...
```

Gets every matching element nested within ancestor element

```
$(ancestor element(s)).children(target elements).each(...
```

Gets every matching element nested directly within ancestor element

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).find('div').each(function() {
    let txt = $(this).text();
    if (txt.includes('Dog 1')) {
      $(this).addClass('dog1');
    }
    if (txt.includes('Dog 2')) {
      $(this).addClass('dog2');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.dog1 {
  color: red;
}

.dog2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Dog 1 Name</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 1 Age</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 1 Weight</span></div>
<div>
  <span>Date of last appointment</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 1 Number</span></div>
<div><span>Acceptance</span></div>
<div>
  <div><span>Dog 1 Allergies</span></div>
</div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Details</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Name</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Name</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Age</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Weight</span></div>
<div><span>Date of last appointment</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Number</span></div>
<div><span>Acceptance</span></div>
<div><span>Dog 2 Allergies</span></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```